# aws amplify javascript invalidate token on signOut

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, logout

I am using javascript version of aws amplify in my reactjs application.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js

When I call signOut method as mentioned in the document below:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a047ce73/packages/aws-amplify-react/src/Auth/SignOut.tsx#L109

code:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signOut() {
    try {
        await Auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}
```

It just clears data from local storage and cookies. I want it to invalidate id token as well as access token. These tokens can still be used to access AppSync or API Gateway. We can use `await Auth.signOut({global: true});` But there is a difference between these 2 methods. The former is used to signOut from the current session, but the other is used to signOut users from all the devices.

I read about calling `invalidateTokens(true)` here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/pull/2415

Is this available in javascript version of aws-amplify? Please let me know any alternate solution to invalidate tokens on `Auth.signOut()` call.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the amplify documentation,

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/react-native/#sign-out

```
Amazon Cognito now supports token revocation, and Amplify (from version 4.1.0) will revoke Amazon Cognito tokens if the application is online. This means the Cognito refresh token cannot be used anymore to generate new Access and Id Tokens.
```

You need to use the RevokeToken function to invalidate the token as documented in this one
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#revokeToken-property

```js
var params = {
  ClientId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Token: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ClientSecret: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.revokeToken(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Another option is to use the revoke endpoint.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/revocation-endpoint.html